# Making top-level functions in a package

Tags: python, python-2.7, package

I'm making a package in Python 2.7, designed to replace [PyCLIPS](http://pyclips.sourceforge.net/web/) in a limited capacity.

This package uses top level functions so that the CLIPS expert system can be accessed more directly. Running `from clips import *` means that functions like `Assert()`, which will assert a fact in the expert system, can be used from the top level.

I need to recreate this so that I can simply replace `from clips import *` with `from PyCLIPS2 import *` in some legacy code and hopefully not change anything else.

Currently the structure of my package is like this:

```
PyCLIPS2
├── __init__.py [1]
├── system
|   ├── __init__.py [2]
|   └── main.py
└── tests
    ├── __init__.py [3]
    └── test_all.py
```

Inside of `__init__.py [1]` I currently have

```
from system import *

_main_object = Main()

def Assert(assertion):
    return _main_object.Facts.Assert(assertion)
```

This lets me do what I want. It means when I import the package it will initialise an instance of `Main()` and tie the top level functions to the relevant functions/methods inside of it.

The problem is, there are a lot of these functions/methods. If I carry on as I am I'm going to have to write one of these functions inside of `__init__.py` for every function or method I want top level access to. I'm also going to have to keep them updated if anything changes.

I'm sure there is a far better way of doing this, that hopefully doesn't require me to write out each of these functions and maintain them. If anybody has any suggestions for getting access to these functions from the top level that is more pythonic or leads to a clearer namespace or is just less horrible, I really would like to hear them :) (alternatively, something that can write these functions for me would also be a great help) Thank you.

Comment: First things first: please, for the love of all that is good and holy, move to py3. py2 will cease to exist in the very near future

Comment: @inspectorG4dget out of my hands unfortunately :( the system I'm writing this for is in py2 and I can't change that